# How to display day first with pd.to_datetime()?

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with date columns in the format: day / month / year

They are in string/object format.

I want to convert them to datetime.

Sample date, 5th of January 2016: `'05/01/2016'`

However `pd.to_datetime` is confusing the day and month.

Here is what I've tried:

```
pd.to_datetime('05/01/2016')

Timestamp('2016-05-01 00:00:00')
```

This has given me `Year - Month - Day`

I want `Day - Month - Year` as in: `05-01-2016`

What I have tried:

```
pd.to_datetime('05/01/2016',dayfirst=True)

Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00')
```

This is correct, but it's not the format I want, which is `'05-01-2016'`

So I tried this:

```
pd.to_datetime('05/01/2016',dayfirst=True,format='%d/%m/%Y')

Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00')
```

There's no difference.

How can I do it? How can I force it to display the datetime as `'05-01-2016'`

Comment: you can do this by `strftime()` but the date is considered as string not datetime dtype

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the timestamp format (to my knowledge), but you can convert it to `string` in the wanted format like so :

```py
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> pd.to_datetime('05/01/2016', dayfirst=True, format='%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
'05-01-2016'
```

Comment: I can't convert it to string because I wanted to do some operations on the columns. Days difference between dates etc etc. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is to change the display options:

```
pd.set_option("display.date_dayfirst", True)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options

but it's not working... Else you convert the datetime type to str:

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('05/01/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y')
print(ts)
# Timestamp('2016-01-05 00:00:00')

ts = ts.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
print(ts)
# '05-01-2016'
```

Or just replace '/' by '-':

```
print('05/01/2016'.replace('/', '-'))
# '05-01-2016'
```